# c++: check for an object of a class in an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

suppose i have a class Element which is,

```
class Element {
private:
    int value;
public:
    void setValue(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

and i store the objects of this class in an array.
Now how can i check if my array of object contains a certain object of class Element.I have tried matching the values of the object using this function...is there any better ways?

```
bool contains(Element e)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(elements[i].getValue()==e.getValue()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the "elements" array?

Comment: First of all you are using python like 'for else' loop in your code. In c++ it won't work like in python. "Else" is part of "if else" control flow construct so your for loop will end on 0'th element. Except that your code should work.

Comment: also forgot to set size in the function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a C++ container like std::array and then use std::find_if.

If you prefer to extend your code, you could overload the `operator==` using

```
bool operator==(const Element& lhs, const Element& rhs) {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}
```

then you can use

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    if(elements[i]==e) return true;
```

EDIT:

since `Element.value` is private you may want to make this a method of `Element`

```
bool Element::operator==(const Element& other) {
    return value == other.value
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `value` member is private. Did you intend to use `getValue()` or implement it as a member function? The const-correctness will need to be fixed to use the `getValue()` member function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a C++ container like [stds::array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) or [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to hold your elements and using [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) to search through it.

If you are using a compiler that supports C++11 syntax then you can use std::find_if like this:

```
int main () 
{
    std::vector<Element> myvector;

    // fill vector

   int valueToCompare = 1234;

   auto it = std::find_if(begin(myvector), end(myvector), [=](const Element& e) {return e.getValue() == valueToCompare;});

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes i did and it compiled,just wanted to know if it was all right to do so

Comment: @SaifulIslam Your if logic is wrong. The return false statement should be outside the for loop without the else. Otherwise if you don't find what you're looking for in your first item then you will just return false when the item might exist somewhere in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can add comparison operators to your element class and then use stl algorithms or stl like algorithms to determine if an element is in the container.

```
class Element {
private:
    int value;
public:
    Element(int v) : value(v) {}
    Element(Element const& e) : value(e.value) {}

    Element & operator=(Element const& e) {
        value = e.value;
    }

    bool operator==(Element const& e) const {
        return value == e.value;
    }

    bool operator!=(Element const& e) const {
        return value != e.value;
    }

    void setValue(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Now you can do something like this.

```
std::vector<Element> elements;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    elements.push_back(Element(i));
}

 // Find the element with the value 4
auto found = std::find(elements.begin(), elements.end(), Element(4));
if(found != elements.end()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Or use a loop like what you described.

```
Element toFind(4);

for(auto it = elements.begin(); it != elements.end(); ++it) {
     if(*it == toFind) {
       // Do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can implement the equal-comparison operator

```
class Element {
private:
    int value;
public:
    // btw. These setters and getters are Java style, not C++ style.
    void setValue(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
    // note that a getter should be const. It doesn't change the object.
    auto getValue() const -> int {
        return value;
    }
    auto operator == (const Element& other) const -> bool {
        return value == other.value;
    }
    auto operator != (const Element& other) const -> bool {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};
```

Now you can use std::find():

```
auto contains(const Element& e) -> bool
{
    auto end = elements + size; // pointers can be used as iterators as well.
    return std::find(elements, end, e) != end;
}
```

You should prefer `std::vector` or `std::array` over raw arrays. `std::array` does not add any overhead but makes the interface more consistent with other `std::`-containers. `std::vector` is used for dynamically sized arrays. It handles all the allocation, initialization, destruction, deallocation, etc. for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answers may be good for expert programmers, I believe at your level, Adkison, you would like a simpler response.

```
bool contains(Element e)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(elements[i].getValue()==e.getValue()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

OK, so one problem is that elements doesn't have a value, and neither does size.  It should be passed in as a parameter.  We'll also use const-& on e, so that it need not be copied (although that's not a big cost here).

```
bool contains  (const Element elements[], int size, const Element& e) ...
```

(Yes, we could pass in elements as a vector, but let's keep it simple for now.)

I believe the problem you're noting is that it never gets past looking at the 0th element.  Trace through and you'll see why.  Suppose that element #0 is equal to `e`; your function returns true, and is done.  Suppose that it isn't equal:  your function returns false, and is done.  What about all the other elements?  Shouldn't we check them too, at least if element #0 isn't what we wanted?

So:  when *should* we return false?  When when we've gone thru the *whole list* and not found `e`.

```
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(elements[i].getValue()==e.getValue()) return true;

    return false;
```

This version doesn't return false until it's looked through the whole array, and failed to find e.